# How to avoid left and right spacing in html?

Tags: html, css

I tried putting p-0 to cover the left right spaces but still I get the same spacing.
[spacing_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tDCz.png)

````
     <div class="container fluid p-0">
        <!-- First child -->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-info">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <img src = "./images/1.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">```
````

Comment: can you share css also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Bootstrap is being used, and the spacing on the sides is due to the `container` class. To remove the spacing, you can simply delete the `container` class from the HTML code. This is because the container class in Bootstrap applies a fixed width and padding to the element.
Consider that removing this class may affect the layout of the content, so adjustments may need to be made to the styles.